# runtime clang/clang++ with non-standard gcc install?

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++

Is there a way to get clang/clang++ to use a gcc/g++ installation in a non-standard (i.e. not /usr) place?

I'm trying to get AMD's AOCC 4.0 compiler to work.  They provide a pre-compiled version that you just unpack.  The problem is that it seems to assume gcc is in /usr/lib/gcc/...  In my case I'm on CentOS 7 so that's gcc 4.8.5.  I want to use newer gcc's install in /sw/opt (and managed with environment modules) but even if the gcc is in my path, clang only finds that 4.8.5 version in /usr.  This is also a problem in that I have a cluster that has *no* default gcc installed (but many gcc versions installed in /cluster/sw) and I can't get clang to see them.

When I want LLVM I usually just build from scratch and specify GCC_INSTALL_PREFIX but that only seems to be useful at build time and since AMD only provides executables I'm out of luck.

Ideally I'd like to get clang/clang++ to point to another gcc (en mass: include, libs, etc...) or not be dependent on gcc at all.

AOCC seems to be based on 14.0.6 if that matters:

```
AMD clang version 14.0.6 (CLANG: AOCC_4.0.0-Build#434 2022_10_28) (based on LLVM Mirror.Version.14.0.6)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /sw/opt/aocc-compiler-4.0.0/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

After more poking around I've discovered that there is a clang option "--gcc-toolchain" that seems to address this.  Some clang documentation also lists an option "--gcc-install-dir" but neither the 14.0.6 based version of AOCC nor the 16.0.0 based version of OneAPI (2023.0) seem to recognize it.  I don't see it in the output of "clang --help" either so who knows.